# How to use Dart Frog in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, dart, dart-frog

How can we create and use a dart project of Dart Frog in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

First open the project

[image]

After, setup the Dart Lib path on the project settings
[image]

Now, you have to set up a Script Shell configuration to run your project
[image]
[image]

Done :)